# CSS float issue?

Tags: css

I'm having some trouble getting a float right on my website. I'm floating an image over to the right, and the text on the left wraps around the image... as long as the browser isn't too wide. I have an `<h2>` under that paragraph that tends to creep up and go on top of that image.

Comment: I would avoid using text shadow for body text, it looks awful.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `clear:right;` to the CSS rules for your `h2`. That should do it.

Comment: Or, `clear:both` to handle the case where an image is floated to the left.